# Prevent creation of an account with < 0 OR > 10,000

Tags: c#, console-application

I currently have a program that makes bank accounts and stores them but I am trying to add code to prevent a user from setting up an account with a negative balance or a balance that exceeds 10,000.

I have declared `private decimal balance = 0;` in order to set the initial balance to 0 for everyone, it is then later on that they enter the amount they wish to store. What I am trying to do is stop people from creating their account with < 0 OR > 10,000

**This is the IF statement I have so far**

```
public virtual bool BalanceRange(decimal amount)
        {
            if ((balance < 0) || (balance > 10000))
            {
                return false; //OR message "Amount Not Allowed";
            }
            this.balance = amount;
            return true; 
        }
```

The point of this IF statement is to check the amount that the user wishes to store in their bank account, the number is inputted within the Main method as shown below:

```
public static void Main()
        {
            CustomerAccount test = new CustomerAccount("Fred", 11000);
            Console.WriteLine(test.GetName());
            Console.WriteLine(test.GetBalance());
        }
```

What this does is create an account with the Name of Fred and with the amount 11,000. My IF statement should reject the creation of this account as the amount is exceeding the amount I set the if statement to check for(10,000) but that does not seem to be happening and I am not sure why

It may be caused by this. This is the class used for the GetBalance() test so I was thinking that my IF statement needs to be placed within this.

```
public virtual decimal GetBalance()
        {
            return this.balance;
        }
```

The constructor:

```
public interface IAccount
    {
        bool PayInFunds(decimal amount);
        bool WithdrawFunds(decimal amount);
        bool BalanceRange(decimal amount);
        decimal GetBalance();
        string RudeLetterString();
        string GetName();
        bool SetName(string inName);
    }
```

Comment: What is the question? Do you have any special problem? Errors? And how does the method where this code comes from look like?

Comment: The right syntax is `if ((balance < 0) || (balance > 10000))`

Comment: Please post all relevant code so that we can compile and run our tests.

Comment: And one on http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Enigmativity I have edited my answer with relevant code

Comment: I don't think `BalanceRange` is clearly named for a function that checks an amount for validity, and it *should not* set the balance, but just return a bool.

Comment: Also, C# has properties, so you can have `public Balance { get { return balance; } }` instead of get and set functions.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking the balance before you set it, so it'll be always 0. The check passes, and then you set the illegal number. Check the amount parameter, not the balance field.

```
    public virtual bool BalanceRange(decimal amount)
    {
        if ((amount < 0) || (amount> 10000))
        {
            return false; //OR message "Amount Not Allowed";
        }
        this.balance = amount;
        return true; 
    }
```

Comment: When I run the console app, it is still allowing me to create the account as the name Fred with 11000 is displayed.

Comment: I can't begin to answer that: you don't show the code in your constructor. How is BalanceRange called? Remember that if you use `new` you should return an instance, what will you return when account creation failed? A Null Reference? Then you're subsequent method calls will fail. The only thing that I could see that was blatantly wrong (except for the points mentioned above), was the fact you were checking a number before setting it.

Comment: I have added the constructor to my original post and the BalanceRange is called in there. If the account reference failed I would either return a null or a message explaining why it failed.

Comment: You do realize that an interface is not a constructor? And if you return a null, `test.GetName()` would throw an exception. I suggest to think about the technical design a bit more before starting to write code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I cannot comment, so this way to ask, where do you even call the BalanceRange method?

I'd expect if even then somewhere in the constructor, but you can't call the constructor, which then rejects to create a object.

You could try something like this in your class with a privat constructor:

```
public static CustomerAccount AccountFactory(string name, int amount)
{
  if ((balance < 0) || (balance > 
    return null; //OR message "Amount Not Allowed";
  return new CustomerAccount(name, amount)
}
```

Comment: I am calling the BalanceRange method within an Account Class along with every other method.